# How to extract items from elements in a list to a new list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Foo

```
List<Foo> fooList = [
  Foo("Zero", 0.0, 0.0),
  Foo("One", 1.0, 0.0),
  Foo("Two", 0.0, 1.0),
  Foo("Three", 1.0, 1.0),
];

class Foo {
  String name;
  double bar;
  double baz;

  Foo(this.name, this.bar, this.baz);
}
```

Is there an easy way to extract and make a list of only `baz`?

I've made it work with a `for`-loop

```
List<double> values = <double>[];
for(var item in fooList) {
  values.add(item.baz);
}
```

but I am hoping there are easier ways than that. Something like `List<double>.from<fooList.baz>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do this by mapping.

```dart
final bazList = fooList.map((fooListItem) => fooListItem.baz).toList();
```

`bazList` is a new array of baz items from the sequence of `fooList`